# DOM Window event before painting

Tags: javascript, html, dom, events

Is it possible to catch an event from the window after HTML is loaded, but before the actual painting happens? Or to access DOM nodes prior to painting to the screen? I'd like to change the style of an element before painting to avoid a visual flicker.

This is the closest I've gotten, but if you refresh the page, you can see the box for a split second before the height change is applied.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <style>
      #container {
        width: 200px;
        height: 200px;
        border: solid;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="container"></div>
    <script>
      window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
        document.getElementById("container").style.height = 0;
      });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Why not just alter the CSS?

Comment: Set the `visibility` to `hidden` in CSS, set the height in JS, then set the `visibility` to `visible`. Or use `display` with `none` and `block`, depending on your needs. There is no event for what you are asking. Do some searches for "FOUC" (flash of unstyled content).

Comment: @jhpratt it's for a React hook I'm trying to make to control animations (the scope of which is beyond this conversation)

Comment: Thanks @HereticMonkey for the response. I figured as much, was just hoping for the contrary...

Answer (score 0):

If you didn't want to mess with the CSS you could create the element with Javascript and synchronously add it in.

```
window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
  let container = document.createElement("div");

  container.id = "container";
  container.style.height = 0;
  document.body.appendChild(container);
});
```